# How do you explain many optimal models in penalized Logistic regression?

Tags: regression, lasso, ridge-regression, regularization

I am building penalized logistic regression using Lasso and Ridge methods. I know that the best model chosen by the program is which has `alpha = 1 and lambda = 0.06`.  But how do you explain the existence of many couples of parameters alpha and lambda giving optimal models (where Accuracy =1)? For example, for these couples of parameters (0.8,0.01),(1.0,0.01),(1.0,0.02), we have optimal models...

The code:

```
set.seed(seed)

cs_data_train <- DATA_BASE[train_set, ]
cs_data_test <- DATA_BASE[-train_set, ]

glmnet_grid <- expand.grid(alpha = c(0,  .1,  .2, .4, .6, .8, 1),
                           lambda = seq(.01, .2, length = 20))
glmnet_ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)
glmnet_fit <- train(OUTCOME ~ ., data = cs_data_train,
                    method = "glmnet",
                    preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
                    tuneGrid = glmnet_grid,
                    trControl = glmnet_ctrl)
```

Then the output is:

```
glmnet 

4620 samples
  29 predictor
   2 classes: '0', '1' 

Pre-processing: centered (149), scaled (149) 
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 4158, 4158, 4158, 4158, 4158, 4158, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  alpha  lambda  Accuracy   Kappa    
  0.0    0.01    0.8893939  0.7774836
  0.0    0.02    0.8893939  0.7774836
  0.0    0.03    0.8885281  0.7757412
  0.0    0.04    0.8779221  0.7543317
  0.0    0.05    0.8675325  0.7333642
  0.0    0.06    0.8612554  0.7206986
  0.0    0.07    0.8543290  0.7066855
  0.0    0.08    0.8504329  0.6988230
  0.0    0.09    0.8443723  0.6865703
  0.0    0.10    0.8400433  0.6778066
  0.0    0.11    0.8361472  0.6699275
  0.0    0.12    0.8331169  0.6637698
  0.0    0.13    0.8309524  0.6594043
  0.0    0.14    0.8296537  0.6567584
  0.0    0.15    0.8270563  0.6515089
  0.0    0.16    0.8246753  0.6466761
  0.0    0.17    0.8222944  0.6418430
  0.0    0.18    0.8199134  0.6369969
  0.0    0.19    0.8168831  0.6308568
  0.0    0.20    0.8151515  0.6273344
  0.1    0.01    0.9411255  0.8817949
  0.1    0.02    0.9086580  0.8163165
  0.1    0.03    0.8904762  0.7796019
  0.1    0.04    0.8803030  0.7590427
  0.1    0.05    0.8714286  0.7411121
  0.1    0.06    0.8658009  0.7297661
  0.1    0.07    0.8584416  0.7149017
  0.1    0.08    0.8543290  0.7065741
  0.1    0.09    0.8504329  0.6986993
  0.1    0.10    0.8478355  0.6934132
  0.1    0.11    0.8454545  0.6885879
  0.1    0.12    0.8430736  0.6837597
  0.1    0.13    0.8400433  0.6776377
  0.1    0.14    0.8378788  0.6732583
  0.1    0.15    0.8359307  0.6693177
  0.1    0.16    0.8344156  0.6662373
  0.1    0.17    0.8337662  0.6649162
  0.1    0.18    0.8329004  0.6631445
  0.1    0.19    0.8316017  0.6604880
  0.1    0.20    0.8305195  0.6582842
  0.2    0.01    0.9532468  0.9061740
  0.2    0.02    0.9112554  0.8215160
  0.2    0.03    0.8945887  0.7878405
  0.2    0.04    0.8846320  0.7677195
  0.2    0.05    0.8781385  0.7546356
  0.2    0.06    0.8746753  0.7476490
  0.2    0.07    0.8688312  0.7358789
  0.2    0.08    0.8619048  0.7218689
  0.2    0.09    0.8556277  0.7091517
  0.2    0.10    0.8523810  0.7025681
  0.2    0.11    0.8484848  0.6946797
  0.2    0.12    0.8458874  0.6894193
  0.2    0.13    0.8437229  0.6850310
  0.2    0.14    0.8415584  0.6806422
  0.2    0.15    0.8363636  0.6700747
  0.2    0.16    0.8344156  0.6661226
  0.2    0.17    0.8335498  0.6643568
  0.2    0.18    0.8318182  0.6608323
  0.2    0.19    0.8313853  0.6599502
  0.2    0.20    0.8300866  0.6573041
  0.4    0.01    0.9872294  0.9744139
  0.4    0.02    0.9183983  0.8358886
  0.4    0.03    0.9047619  0.8083648
  0.4    0.04    0.8991342  0.7969970
  0.4    0.05    0.8878788  0.7742399
  0.4    0.06    0.8822511  0.7628754
  0.4    0.07    0.8781385  0.7545657
  0.4    0.08    0.8720779  0.7422980
  0.4    0.09    0.8655844  0.7291111
  0.4    0.10    0.8588745  0.7154915
  0.4    0.11    0.8538961  0.7053790
  0.4    0.12    0.8512987  0.7000941
  0.4    0.13    0.8497835  0.6970093
  0.4    0.14    0.8454545  0.6881825
  0.4    0.15    0.8437229  0.6846173
  0.4    0.16    0.8419913  0.6810437
  0.4    0.17    0.8398268  0.6765972
  0.4    0.18    0.8374459  0.6717235
  0.4    0.19    0.8337662  0.6641936
  0.4    0.20    0.8329004  0.6623775
  0.6    0.01    0.9995671  0.9991335
  0.6    0.02    0.9458874  0.8913305
  0.6    0.03    0.9164502  0.8319373
  0.6    0.04    0.9073593  0.8135667
  0.6    0.05    0.9015152  0.8017627
  0.6    0.06    0.8974026  0.7934540
  0.6    0.07    0.8859307  0.7702013
  0.6    0.08    0.8748918  0.7477933
  0.6    0.09    0.8679654  0.7337078
  0.6    0.10    0.8640693  0.7257815
  0.6    0.11    0.8601732  0.7178373
  0.6    0.12    0.8538961  0.7050521
  0.6    0.13    0.8480519  0.6931004
  0.6    0.14    0.8430736  0.6829322
  0.6    0.15    0.8385281  0.6735822
  0.6    0.16    0.8324675  0.6611737
  0.6    0.17    0.8238095  0.6434110
  0.6    0.18    0.8179654  0.6314211
  0.6    0.19    0.8114719  0.6180772
  0.6    0.20    0.8015152  0.5976493
  0.8    0.01    1.0000000  1.0000000
  0.8    0.02    0.9995671  0.9991335
  0.8    0.03    0.9989177  0.9978338
  0.8    0.04    0.9430736  0.8856538
  0.8    0.05    0.9099567  0.8187660
  0.8    0.06    0.8926407  0.7836762
  0.8    0.07    0.8794372  0.7568573
  0.8    0.08    0.8714286  0.7405558
  0.8    0.09    0.8621212  0.7216059
  0.8    0.10    0.8534632  0.7039345
  0.8    0.11    0.8452381  0.6871445
  0.8    0.12    0.8424242  0.6813920
  0.8    0.13    0.8417749  0.6800643
  0.8    0.14    0.8417749  0.6800643
  0.8    0.15    0.8417749  0.6800643
  0.8    0.16    0.8268398  0.6494935
  0.8    0.17    0.7930736  0.5803180
  0.8    0.18    0.7930736  0.5803180
  0.8    0.19    0.7930736  0.5803180
  0.8    0.20    0.7930736  0.5803180
  1.0    0.01    1.0000000  1.0000000
  1.0    0.02    1.0000000  1.0000000
  1.0    0.03    1.0000000  1.0000000
  1.0    0.04    1.0000000  1.0000000
  1.0    0.05    1.0000000  1.0000000
  1.0    0.06    1.0000000  1.0000000
  1.0    0.07    0.9523810  0.9037432
  1.0    0.08    0.8417749  0.6800643
  1.0    0.09    0.8417749  0.6800643
  1.0    0.10    0.8417749  0.6800643
  1.0    0.11    0.8417749  0.6800643
  1.0    0.12    0.8417749  0.6800643
  1.0    0.13    0.8417749  0.6800643
  1.0    0.14    0.8417749  0.6800643
  1.0    0.15    0.8417749  0.6800643
  1.0    0.16    0.8019481  0.5985388
  1.0    0.17    0.7930736  0.5803180
  1.0    0.18    0.7930736  0.5803180
  1.0    0.19    0.7930736  0.5803180
  1.0    0.20    0.7930736  0.5803180

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final values used for the model were alpha = 1 and lambda = 0.06.
```

How do you explain this please?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Check the [Deviance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_(statistics)). If it is equal for those models it could be a big extremum plateau.

Comment: what is there to explain? The data are relatively easy to separate and there is more than one model that can do this. Also, accuracy is a bad measure

Comment: @rep_ho, so what should I do to select the best model if accuracy is a bad measure?